# Parity of quantum numbers of combined system of two spin-1 particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, spin-statistics

I'm looking at the following problem:

> Two identical particles of spin $1$ have centre of mass at rest. The
> particles have combined spin $\mathbf{S}$, relative orbital angular
> momentum $\mathbf{L}$ and total angular momentum
> $\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{L}+\mathbf{S}$. Let $j$, $l$ and $s$ be the
> quantum numbers corresponding to the operators $\mathbf{J}^2$,
> $\mathbf{L}^2$ and $\mathbf{S}^2$ of the combined system. Show that
> $l+s$ must be even. If $j=1$, then what are the possible values of $l$
> and $s$?

What I have so far: I have shown earlier that if you form states $|s,\sigma \rangle$ by combining the states $|1,\sigma_1 \rangle$ and $|1, \sigma_2 \rangle$, then the state is symmetric under the exchange $\sigma_1 \leftrightarrow \sigma_2$ for $s=2$ or $s=0$, and antisymmetric for $s=1$. This seems to have something to do with the spin-statistics theorem — we have a combined system of two bosons so the system is symmetric under the exchange of the two identical particles but I don't see how this links to the orbital angular momentum of the system.